# change the data in the file change numbers

Tags: python

I have a problem and I need to solve it, specifically reduce all the numbers
example I have a text file
input from file

```
1/1/1 text data
20/20/20 text data 1
300/300/300 text data 2 
10/10/10 text data
```

this script should do it

```
def digit_root (n):
     if n == 0: return 0
     return (n - 1)% 9 + 1
print (digit_root (20))
```

and the output should be

```
1/1/1 text data
2/2/2 text date 1
3/3/3 text date 2
1/1/1 text data 3

file =  open("dadd.txt",encoding='ISO-8859-1')
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    words = line.split()
    print(words[0])
```

this will only give numbers
the question is how used
digit_root  to those numbers

This script should clean each row sequentially and what they need to do is change the digits on each row from file

Comment: So, just to verify, you want to divide by the 10th, 100th, 1000th, or whatever place it is that makes your number the smallest? So what would 250/250/250 become? 25/25/25?

Comment: @alien_jedi `def digit_root (n):
     if n == 0: return 0
     return (n - 1)% 9 + 1
print (digit_root (20))` this code to do it right however i don't know how to write it    (you example is  7/7/7 hay this is text)

Comment: You simply read the file, split each line on whitespaces, and then print the resulting list. You never process the lines on the file, so why do you expect your code to give you the output you want?

Comment: You seem to have figured out how to convert `200` to `2` using your `digit_root` function, so what is stopping you from applying that function to the appropriate elements in the `words` list? If you tried it and ran into a problem, what was _that_ problem?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi the problem was that i didn't know how to write it format I need to remake it from someone who understands it more im new programer

Comment: Go through your program step-by-step . Say you are in the first iteration of the loop, reading the first line of the file. What do you have in `words`? What do you need to do to `words` to get the numbers in the first part of the line? (hint: You already used this function in your code). After you do this, you probably have the numbers in that part as _strings_, so how would you convert them to integers?...

Comment: ...Once you have the integer, you can call your `digit_root()` to get the converted number. Then, how would you format this number into a string again so you can write it to the output? Programming is just problem-solving on a computer, and like any other problem-solving technique, you need to _break down the problem_ into smaller, more manageable bits and then come up with (or look for) a solution to those smaller bits. [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I don't know how to write it makes me have problems   otherwise I wouldn't ask here I know all the codes can do it: D but I can't connect them above all, it makes me split

Comment: @alien_jedi updated is mi ask thanx for help

Comment: @PranavHosangadi it gives me a problem formatting print (words [0]) gives format only numbers

100/100/100 but how to reduce it? I don't know anymore and the text behind it would be different, but this is beyond my power

there are duplicates of 100/100/100 and next 1/1/1 + text

Comment: @ZionAlt What if your file contains `250/250/250` do you want it to become `25/25/25` or `2/2/2`? Or is it always `xy/xy/xy` where `x` is a number in `{1, 2, ..., 9}` and `y` is zero or more `0`s?

Comment: @oda it becomes `7/7/7` ( https://mathsisfun.com/numbers/digital-root.html )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose `"in.txt"` is

```
1/1/1 text data
20/20/20 text data 1
300/300/300 text data 2
10/10/10 text data 3
250/250/250 text data 4
```

The following program opens two files, `"in.txt"` and `"out.txt"`. The former file is opened for reading and the latter for writing. As we iterate over the lines of `f_in`, we create a temporary variable `temp` that is initially assigned the return value of `line.split('/')` which is a list of the "words" in the line, using `"/"` as the delimiter string. We then split the last element of `temp` (i.e. element `temp[-1]`) into a list of two "words", using the first occurrence of consecutive whitespace as the delimiter and then assign this to `temp[-1:]`, effectively extending `temp` by one element. We then use an f-string to help us write each line to `"out.txt"` in our desired format.

The argument `maxsplit = 2` in the first `split()` call is to ensure that `temp` initially has only three elements (before we extend it by one). If we did not specify anything for `maxsplit`, the text to the right of the numbers may have `"/"` somewhere which would make `temp` have more than three elements initially, which would make the below code fail. Similarly, `maxsplit = 1` is used in the second `split()` call along with the first argument equal to `None` to split the string at the first occurrence of consecutive whitespace.

```
def digit_root(n):
    return (n - 1) % 9 + 1 if n else 0

with open("in.txt") as f_in, open("out.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        temp = line.split('/', maxsplit = 2)
        temp[-1:] = temp[-1].split(None, maxsplit = 1)

        # formatted string
        out_line = f"{digit_root(int(temp[0]))}/{digit_root(int(temp[1]))}/" \
                   f"{digit_root(int(temp[2]))} {temp[3]}"
        print(out_line, end = "")

        # write out_line to "out.txt"
        f_out.write(out_line)
```

Output (from `print`)

```
1/1/1 text data
2/2/2 text data 1
3/3/3 text data 2
1/1/1 text data 3
7/7/7 text data 4
```

`"out.txt"` (after running above program)

```
1/1/1 text data
2/2/2 text data 1
3/3/3 text data 2
1/1/1 text data 3
7/7/7 text data 4
```

Comment: thanx :D you :D vs mi bad code :D          ` n = txt.split("/")
        n[0] = int(n[0])
        n[1] = int(n[1])
        n[2] = int(n[2])
        a=(digit_root(n[0]))
        b=(digit_root(n[1]))
        c=(digit_root(n[2]))
        print(a,":",b,":",c,sep='',line, file=open(""+str(dad)+".txt", "a",encoding='ISO-8859-1'))`

Comment: No worries @ZionAlt

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1\tVe'
bro what is this problem? solved please?   encoding='ISO-8859-1' this nod help :(

Comment: @ZionAlt One second. What has happened is that the last number in that line has a tab character rather than a space separating the `1` and the `Ve`.

Comment: @ZionAlt Try `temp[-1:] = temp[-1].split(None, 1)`. Does this fix your problem?

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '8\tJsou mezi lidmi nÄ\x9bkteÅ\x99Ã\xad, kdoÅ¾ Å\x99Ã\xadkajÃ\xad'

Comment: Could you maybe update your question to include the line that has `8\tJsou mezi lidmi nÄ\x9bkteÅ\x99Ã\xad, kdoÅ¾ Å\x99Ã\xadkajÃ\xad` in your sample input? I need to see the entire line.

Comment: Wait a second. @ZionAlt Are the numbers separated by a `:` or a `/`?

Comment: just change the numbers and the rest of the ad is the text as big as the numbers were added

Comment: temp = line.split(':') im change :D

Comment: Ah okay. I see. Your line has more than 2 `:`'s. One second.

Comment: Try `temp = line.split(':', maxsplit = 2)`

Comment: yes this working thanx for you time

Comment: Phew! Happy it works! Happy coding!

Comment: thank you too now now i have to sort from the biggest to the smallest number: D I'll still enjoy the work